# Problems with Google Earth on Linux Mint

Tags: google-earth, linux-mint

I just installed the latest version of Google Earth, and this is what I see when I start it:

[image]

The "background" is just another nemo window that happened to be open.
I'm running Linux Mint 17.3. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Nvidia Nouveau or Intel non-modesetting display/3D drivers? If so, those have known incompatibilities with Earth Pro, so try using different drivers.

Comment: I'm using Nvidia Nouveau. But recently I got an update for Google Earth, and the problem has been solved.